# Jquery Mobile ui classes are not added on ReactJS elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jquery-mobile

I am working with `jquery mobile` and `ReactJS` for my mobile website. So I am opening slide using `JQM transition` which contains `ReactJS Component`. How I am doing this is below code:

```
$(".mobi-page-create").click(function(){
    $(document).bind('pagecreate', function(){
        ReactDOM.render(<MobileSearch />, document.getElementById('MobileSearch'));
    });
});
```

The *ReactJS Component* `<MobileSearch />` contains `Radio input` element.

The Problem is that the JQM UI classes are added to the container of the page loaded in the slide but not to the `input` fields which are created by ReactJS Component.

How it can be done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding those classes manually to the input elements inside your MobileSearch component?

Comment: If some method somehow adds classes automatically to some container that has a React app, then you should try calling that method in your React component lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`. e.g. `componentDidMount() { callSomeFunctionThatAddsClasses(); }`

Comment: @nbkhope no... It also some other data attribute

Comment: And also don't know which method I should call for the `JQM` to initialize it to add classes to `Form` element. because `JQM` adds these classes when page load

Comment: It would be interesting if  you post a snippet... BTW, maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41409019/4845566) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41484070/4845566) is something useful regarding your last comment

Comment: Call `.enhanceWithin()` on containing div/form.

Comment: @Omar: JQM + React: i read this Google thread: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/reactjs/4IMWpFs-B5Y/c892FgvLw28J - is that pair so much faster as JQM only? It is worth?

Comment: @deblocker I didn't try React before. I recommend using an interface to handle data. jQM is poor in that field. Edit: However, it's not going to be easy to integrate both technologies. There'd be some workaround and such.

Comment: [Follow up comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45802775/jquery-mobile-ui-classes-are-not-added-on-reactjs-elements?noredirect=1#comment78585812_45802775): bear in mind that `.enhanceWithin()` handles only newly added elements. It doesn't work as _refresh_ method, otherwise, you have to _refresh_ each widget separately using its' own method. Hectic, isn't?