# jQuery mobile: adding checkbox dynamically

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have no earlier jQuery mobile experience, and now I am trying to add new checkbox dynamically in javascript.

Using (in html head)

```
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css
jquery-1.11.3.min.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
```

part of HTML:

```
<form>
    <fieldset data-role="collapsible">
        <div id="agree" data-role="controlgroup"></div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

part of JAVASCRIPT:

```
var html = '<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1" /><label for="checkbox-1">I agree</label>'; 
$('#agree').html(html); 
$("input[type='checkbox']").checkboxradio("refresh");
```

I am getting only plain checkbox, no any formatting.
What is wrong? Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you please share a working snippet, maybe a JSFiddle, so that we know which version of JQuery you are using?

Comment: here are some full working examples: [Dynamically creating productlists with checkboxes in jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325900/dynamically-creating-productlists-with-checkboxes-in-jquerymobile-proves-difficu/41484070#41484070) and here:  [Jquery Mobile checkbox-list does not update when adding items and :  “refreshing” the script to style it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41404047/jquery-mobile-checkbox-list-does-not-update-when-adding-items-and-refreshing-t/41409019#41409019)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$("[data-role=controlgroup]").enhanceWithin().controlgroup("refresh");
```

I hope this helps you!